# GCM Application server inside web service

Tags: android, web-services, google-cloud-messaging

I created an Android application that allows a user to send a Message to other users. In order to achive this, I used `GCM`. So, a user can send a message using a web service (developed using `Web API` framework), that save the message on the remote database (SQL Server) and contacts the GCM Server for delivering to the recipient the GCM message.

It can happen that the message to GCM is not received, for example because the GCM server is temorary unavailable. So Google suggests to try the resend using an exponential backoff. And this is a problem for my architecture, since I call GCM from inside another WS (the one I created, that is used from a user for sending message to other user). If I try to use exponensial back-off my outer WS should be active, since the GCM return a valid response.

So, seems that calling GCM web service from inside another web service is not a good thing. Is this right? Can you give me any suggestion? What is the most common architecture of IM application that uses GCM ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your problem is that your web service for sending messages to GCM is synchronous (at least that's what I assume based on your question). I.e., it receives the request from your client, sends a request to GCM server and returns a response to your client after getting the response from GCM server.

I suggest that you change the architecture. You web service should receive the message from your client, store it in your DB and return a response to the client.

A separate thread in your server should periodically wake up to see if there are any pending messages in your DB, and try to send them to GCM server. If you get an error from GCM that indicates you should retry later, you update the message in your DB with the timestamp of your next send attempt (and you set the timestamp respecting the exponential back-off requirement). If you get a successful response from GCM, you remove the message from your DB.

Comment: Thank you @Eran. But, using a periodically wakeup system does not make my system near-realtime as requested for Instant Messaging application.

Comment: @Joseph82 Periodic wakeup doesn't have to be with a long period. It could wake every second to check if there are any pending messages to send to GCM server. And if you want to reduce the delay, you can perform the first delivery attempt in the web service that gets the message from the client, and only do retries (if necessary) in the separate thread. I think that solution is less elegant, but it will still work.

Comment: Sure @Eran, but schedule a job with very high frequency I think it does not a good idea. "SQL Agent Job scheduler itself is very light, the minimal interval SQL Server supports natively is 1 minute. If you goal is to let you job response to new files ASAP, then set the schedule to run every 1 minutes. "